# Python dict: mapping keys to a different range under constraints

Tags: python, dictionary, language-features

I have a dictionary `d` wohse keys are `n` integers. The keys are not necessarily consecutive numbers, however, it is known that `d` contains `num_negative` consecutive keys in range `(-num_negative,0)` and `num_positive` consecutive keys in the range `(0,num_positive)`. I want to create from it another dictionary `d2`, whose keys are consecutive integers in the range `[0, n]`, given the following constraints:

(1) the elements that had a key from the group `num_positive` in `d`, will have the same key in `d2`.

(2) the elements that had a negative key `i` from the group `num_negative` in `d`, will have the key `n+i` in `d2`.

**An example**:

```
# num_positive = 2, num_negative = 3, n=8

# num_positive group = {0,1}
# num_negative gorup = {-3,-2,-1}

d = {-6: 'h', -3: 'a', -2: 'b', -1: 'c', 0: 'd', 1: 'e', 68: 'f', 99: 'g'}
d2 = {0: 'd', 1: 'e', 2: 'g', 3: 'h', 4: 'f', 5: 'a', 6: 'b', 7: 'c'}
```

Comment: So show us your code and tell us what it does wrong. BTW, your `d2` doesn't seem to be right according to your constraints. Eg, why did `68:'f'`  become `4:f`, and why did `99:g` become `2:g`?

Comment: @PM2Ring It's correct according to the constraints. The ordering of elements outside the consecutive ranges seems to be undefined. For example, `-6: 'h'` becomes `3: 'h'` which is between two positives (`g` and `f`). I think they just fall wherever they can once the negative consecutive range is taken care of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, items with keys outside either consecutive range have undefined placement in the resulting dictionary. Therefore, in my solution, they are inserted into the resulting dictionary in an arbitrary order using whatever keys are still free in the consecutive range `[0, len(d))`. See the comments for more details.

---

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {-6: 'h', -3: 'a', -2: 'b', -1: 'c', 0: 'd', 1: 'e', 68: 'f', 99: 'g'}
remainder = {}

rPos = range(0, 2 + 1) # Positive consecutive range.
rNeg = range(-3, 0) # Negative consecutive range.
n = len(d)

d2 = OrderedDict([(i, None) for i in range(0, n)])

for k, v in d.items():
    if k in rNeg: # Checks if in negative consecutive range.
        d2[n + k] = v
    elif k in rPos: # Checks if in positive negative range.
        d2[k] = v
    else: # Key is outside of either range.
        remainder[k] = v

for k, v in d2.items():
    if v is None: # Finds a key still available for use.
        # Pops an arbitrary element from the remainder and inserts its
        # value into the new dict using an available key.
        d2[k] = remainder.popitem()[1]
```

---

```
Input: {-6: 'h', -3: 'a', -2: 'b', -1: 'c', 0: 'd', 1: 'e', 68: 'f', 99: 'g'}
Output: OrderedDict([(0, 'd'), (1, 'e'), (2, 'g'), (3, 'f'), (4, 'h'), (5, 'a'), (6, 'b'), (7, 'c')])
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should do it.

```
d1={}

for key,val in d.items(): 
   if key in pos and key<=n :               #the elements that had a key from the group num_positive in d, will have the same key in d2
       d1[key] = val 
   elif key in neg and ((key+n) in range(n+1)) :             #the elements that had a negative key i from the group num_negative in d, will have the key n+i in d2
       d1[key+n] = val
```

#driver values :

```
IN : n = 8
IN : pos = [0,1]
IN : neg = [-3,-2,-1]
IN : d = {-6: 'h', -3: 'a', -2: 'b', -1: 'c', 0: 'd', 1: 'e', 68: 'f', 99: 'g'} 

OUT : d1 = {5: 'a', 6: 'b', 7: 'c', 0: 'd', 1: 'e'}
```

**NOTE :** there are some discrepancies in the OP's output. Few of them behave differently than what's defined.

So, the keys that do not follow given constraints are ignored.

Comment: OP states the output dictionary's `keys are consecutive integers in the range [0, n]`. Also, why would `f` and `g` have those keys? Their original keys are not in the negative consecutive range, therefore `n+i` does not apply.

Comment: @Mark , had posted the wrong output. Have updated now.